# How to add custom entries to generated Android MANIFEST.MF

Tags: android, android-manifest

The Android SDK automatically generates META-INF/MANIFEST.MF when it builds an apk file. Is it possible to add custom entries to this file? I'm using a legacy jar that requires it.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have any evidence that your "legacy JAR" can even read `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` from an APK file?

Comment: I thought so, but now I think it only works with included jar files, not the apk itself. Class.getResource() returns null for non-jar classes. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entries in `META-INF` are generated with [jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jarsigner.html) tool. The format of this file is specified. Thus, even if you add some entries to this file, it seems that the verification process will not pass.

Comment: jarsigner does not generate the manifest. It is often created manually but on the Android SDK generates it.

Comment: "JAR files are the same as zip files, except they also have a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. Such a file will automatically be created when jarsigner signs a zip file" This is a citation from the description of  jarsigner. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html - you can find out that in case of Android jarsigner is responsible for signing and this component creates META-INF folder.

Comment: According to the same docs, jarsigner is just a wrapper for jar. jar CAN add custom entries to a manifest, and jarsigner can pass through the necessary params. :)